# Trying to find the average

Tags: javascript

I need to know why when I try to divide student 1,student 2 and student 3. I think it might be a looping error since the number that it give's me is numbering in the thousands but I don't see how that could be happening.

```
function averageOfThreeScores() {
    var student1;
    var student2;
    var student3;
    var end;
    do {
        student1 = prompt("What are the scorces of students 1?");
        student2 = prompt("What are the scorces of students 2?");
        student3 = prompt("What are the scorces of students 3?");
        end = prompt("Would you like to end, type yes to end.");
        var average = (student1 + student2 + student3) / 3;
    if (average <= 59) {
        document.write(average + " Your score is F <br/>");

    } else if (average <= 69) {
        document.write(average + " Your score is D <br/>");

    } else if (average <= 79) {
        document.write(average + " Your score is C <br/>");

    } else if (average <= 95) {
        document.write(average + "That's a great score <br/>");

    } else if (average <= 100) {
        document.write(average + "God like </br>");

    } else {
        document.write(average + " End <br/>");
    }

}
while (end != "yes");
```

}

Comment: You at least need `(student1 + student2 + student3) / 3;` instead of `student1 + student2 + student3 / 3;` For order of operations, multiplication takes precedence over addition.

Comment: average is a number. try average.toString()

Comment: @matthew Gunn I tried that but it still keeps giving me me a scores of up to 2200 and so on, I'm looking for it to divide the the three students by 3 in order to find the average.

Comment: @lamirap I don't know what you mean? Could you send me a mozilla reference link on using the The to.String method?

Comment: What do you mean by "the division doesn't happen only the multiplication"? Where is multiplication? Your while condition is also strange because you assign numbers to student1, student2 and student3, then in while condition make a boolean "and" operation to be equal to a string?

Comment: @Areca All I want it to do is just add together all the student scores from 1 to 100 and have it divide by 3 so I can find the average from those if statements. Whenever I input numbers into the prompt for students 123 I expect the division of 3 to occur but instead I get a huge number in the thousands popping up. I don't know if that's a while looping error or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expect the sum of student grades to be number but in fact they are concatenated as string. So if user types following values for example:
for student1: 13
for student2: 36
for student3: 50

The average will be 44550 because the sum will be (concatenated strings): 133650

To fix this, just convert the type to number when you get it.

```
student1 = parseInt(prompt("What are the scorces of students 1?"));
student2 = parseInt(prompt("What are the scorces of students 2?"));
student3 = parseInt(prompt("What are the scorces of students 3?"));
```